# gcc version is different when using sudo

Tags: path, sudo, gcc, cmake

I have two versions of gcc installed on my CentOS7 machine: 4.8.5 and 8.3.  If I do:
$ gcc --version
I get 8.3

If I do:
$ sudo gcc --version
I get 4.8.5

How can I get sudo commands to also use 8.3 instead of 4.8.5?  I have the same issue with cmake as well... 3.9.2 for regular user, and 2.8.11 for sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Run `which gcc` and `sudo which gcc`. This will give you full paths for both compilers.

Comment: That is not the answer